# video.js : How to fade out control bar if video is paused

Tags: javascript, css, controls, video.js

I want the control bar to disappear if and during the video is paused.

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: I have the standard code provided by video.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.vjs-fade-out {}
```

Base on their site:

[**Link**](http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls)

Comment: I added `.vjs-default-skin.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-control-bar {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
      -ms-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
       -o-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
          transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
}` to the CSS and this worked!

Comment: nice glad to hear enjoy

Answer (score 0):

in videojs 5, i added

```
.vjs-paused .vjs-control-bar {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

that was all.